# Segment.io HTTP API not collecting events

Tags: httprequest, httpresponse, segment-io, httpapi

The documentation and help for this particular [Segment.io](https://segment.com/docs/sources/server/http/) is limited and sparse, so I hope it's OK to ask in here.

I have just set up a Segment.io workspace and a HTTP API source
[image: HTTP API source visible in the Segment.io UI]

Per the [docs](https://segment.com/docs/sources/server/http/), I sent some POST requests (with Postman) to the `https://api.segment.io/v1/track` and `https://api.segment.io/v1/page` endpoints. The requests were structured like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://api.segment.io/v1/track \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Authorization: My4w3s0m3k3y' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Host: api.segment.io' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 474d7fbe-15af-43d2-b629-61e15945e662,2c3d5fbe-2c09-4fe6-b7ea-a04e3221201b' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.11.0' \
  -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-length: 117' \
  -d '{
  "userId": "abc123",
  "event": "My tests",
  "properties": {
    "name": "test 1"
  }
}'
```

which all returned a 200 response and the following message:

```
{
    "success": true
}
```

However, when I got to my dashboard, no events have been recorded.
[image: flat-lining events graph as seen on the Segment.io UI]

The debugger is also empty
[image: Empty debugger page with text "No Recent Events Seen. Make sure your source is configured correctly."]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

I have been dealing with the same issue.
I found the solution as Todd said.

You should add a header `Authorization: Basic + base64 encoding write key`.

So, you look for the Segment source setting and get the write key.
After that, i have used an [online base64 encoding tool](https://www.base64encode.org/) to encode my write key.
Finally, you should add this header (Authorization) with 'Basic' and the encoded write key.

You should be able to see the tracked event in the Debugging panel in Segment web page.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your write key isn't base64 encoded. When you encode your write key, remember to add the `:` at the end of it, before it's encoded.

Also, for the Authorization key:value, be sure to add `Basic` before the encoded write key. So your Authorization key:value would look like:

> Authorization: Basic {encoded write key}

An example from the [segment documentation](https://segment.com/docs/sources/server/http/#authentication):

> In practice that means taking a Segment source Write Key,'abc123', as the username, adding a colon, and then the password field is left empty. After base64 encoding 'abc123:' becomes 'YWJjMTIzOg=='; and this is passed in the authorization header like so: 'Authorization: Basic YWJjMTIzOg=='.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
const { promisify } = require("util");

var Analytics = require("analytics-node");
var analytics = new Analytics("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", {
  flushAt: 1,
});

const [identify, track] = [
  analytics.identify.bind(analytics),
  analytics.track.bind(analytics),
].map(promisify);


 console.log("user id: ", req.body.event.app_user_id);
  let app_user_id = req.body.event.app_user_id;
  let period_type = req.body.event.period_type;
  let expiration_at_ms = req.body.event.expiration_at_ms;
  let ret = "Initial";
  try {
    await identify({
      userId: app_user_id,
      traits: {
        period_type: period_type,
        expiration_at_ms: expiration_at_ms,
      },
    });
    ret = "Done : Sengment done";
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("err: ", err);
    ret = "Error : " + err;
  }

  return {
    rafsan: ret,
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

I am coming from the future, if you don't find the event you are sending through the api on the debugger and you were following the documentation. The body example provided in the documentation is

```json
{
  "userId": "019mr8mf4r",
  "traits": {
    "email": "pgibbons@example.com",
    "name": "Peter Gibbons",
    "industry": "Technology"
  },
  "context": {
    "ip": "24.5.68.47"
  },
  "timestamp": "2012-12-02T00:30:08.276Z"
}
```

The great about it is the `timestamp` field property, it forces sending it in `2012` which will not show in your segment debugger if you have some active events being sent. Or in other words it is shown in the bare bottom of the debugger which you won't expect.

The solution is to just remove the `timestamp` property from the event body and everything should go okay.

Answer (score -1):

Try to clear your browser's cache or use a different browser. I had the same problem and worked for me.

Hope this helps.